# python azure sdk - Clone Server

Tags: python, azure, sdk

I am in process of writing python script to clone the server in Azure.
I am facing problem while fetching APP disk information.

1. Below code is only capturing the name of application disk. I need their LUN number , caching information, Ids.
2. How to create a destination disks once information is collected.

```
computeClient = ComputeManagementClient(secretCredential,subscriptionid) 
    detailsOfVM = computeClient.virtual_machines.get("AKS-CLUSTER-RG", "DOCKER", expand='instanceView')
    dictOfOSDisk=dict()
    if detailsOfVM.storage_profile.image_reference:
            dictOfOSDisk["publisher"] = detailsOfVM.storage_profile.image_reference.publisher
            dictOfOSDisk["offer"] = detailsOfVM.storage_profile.image_reference.offer
            dictOfOSDisk["sku"] = detailsOfVM.storage_profile.image_reference.sku
            dictOfOSDisk["version"] = detailsOfVM.storage_profile.image_reference.version
    dictOfOSDisk["osType"] = detailsOfVM.storage_profile.os_disk.os_type
    dictOfOSDisk["name"] = detailsOfVM.storage_profile.os_disk.name
    dictOfOSDisk["createOption"] = detailsOfVM.storage_profile.os_disk.create_option)
    dictOfOSDisk["caching"]= detailsOfVM.storage_profile.os_disk.caching
    print(dictOfOSDisk)
    
allDiskOfVmList = [disk.name for disk in detailsOfVM.instance_view.disks]
print(allDiskOfVmList)
```

Comment: As far as I knew, only data disk has LUN number.

Comment: yes , agree and it has cache settings as well. Question is how to fetch this info . I only have diskname with me in variable allDiskOfVmList  ?

Comment: According to my understanding, you want to know how to get the lun number of the data disk you attached to one VM. Right?

Comment: Besides, according to the code you provide, you get osdisk's information, it has no LUN number. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get#osdisk

Comment: Incorrect ....please check these lines of code again . let me run it for you and paste in next comment

Comment: detailsOfVM = computeClient.virtual_machines.get("AKS-CLUSTER-RG", "DOCKER", expand='instanceView')

allDiskOfVmList = [disk.name for disk in detailsOfVM.instance_view.disks]
for item in allDiskOfVmList:
    print(item)

Comment: output of code : [amitadmin@NAT8 azure-python-scripts]$ listsDisks.py
docker-osdisk-20210129-101754
docker-datadisk-000-20210129-101754

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you provide, it just will return the instance view of your disks. It does not contain the LUN number of Azure VM data disks.        For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_03_01.models.virtualmachineinstanceview?view=azure-python).
If you want to get the LUN number of Azure VM data disk, please refer to the following code

```
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, Subscription_Id)

vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(vmGroup, vmName)
dataDisks = vm.storage_profile.data_disks
for disk in dataDisks:
    print(disk.lun)
```

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_03_01.models.storageprofile?view=azure-python)

Comment: No Jim you are missing last 2 lines of code....allDiskOfVmList = [disk.name for disk in detailsOfVM.instance_view.disks]
print(allDiskOfVmList)

Comment: @Amit The code detailsOfVM.instance_view.disks] cannot return the LUN number of Azure VM data disk. It just returns the status of disk https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_06_01.models.virtualmachineinstanceview?view=azure-python, https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rG5I.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjXrf.png